# How does the bundled Android Briefing news app avoid Netguard firewall internet block?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, firewall, samsung-mobile

I am getting 'Notifications' on Samsung S7 edge phone in the notifications bar with "titles" about current events but I have Netguard firewall basically blocking Internet "completely" so either it is able to "escape" Netguard firewall somehow and receive new data over internet/4G or somehow it is getting SMS packets to my phone number which maybe are not blocked. So which is it?

Anyone know or have similar experience with Briefing giving news events updates/notifications even though Internet is completely blocked on all apps including "system apps"? (this is a non-rooted regular T-Mobile phone)

If I click on one of the Briefing notifications with the recent day's news/title the content does not load, so apparently when the full app opens it really is blocked from internet but the notifications somehow still get data.

Comment: One way to check is to put the device in Airplane mode and connect it to a Wi-Fi access point where you are logging all data for an extended period of time. If you see traffic even though the Netguard firewall is on, then it is a firewall issue/phone isn't completely blocked. If no notifications and logs don't show anything then it may be SMS/4G.

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/FAQ.md#FAQ19

"*(19) Why does application XYZ still have internet access?
If you block internet access for an application, there is no way around it. However, applications could access the internet through other (system) applications. For example, Google Play services handles incoming push messages for most applications. You can prevent this by blocking internet access for the other application as well. This can best be diagnosed by checking the global access log (three dot menu, Show log).
Note that some applications keep trying to access the internet, which is done by sending a connection request packet. This packet goes into the VPN sinkhole when internet access for the application is blocked. This packet consists of less than 100 bytes and is counted by Android as outgoing traffic and will be visible in the speed graph notification as well.*"

There is a dedicated support forum here for your next question:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-netguard-root-firewall-t3233012

Comment: I had already blocked ALL/every system applications. Thanks for the response though I will take a look at log you mentioned, sorry for late reply, just noticed this again

Comment: well I guess show log works only in the "paid" pro version...will see sometime if I can get some more info out of logcat with adb etc

Comment: Oh wow cool, seems like you're the actual netguard developer! :)  I've killed my 4G and wifi to see if that finally stops news briefing app and will update on here in a day or two.

Comment: After upgrading to note 9, netguard is not blocking "anything" at all even though absolutely everything is set to be blocked even all system apps. I tried updating to latest same, another note9 same problem, running android 8.1.0 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012476/why-is-netguard-firewall-not-working-not-blocking-anything-on-my-note-9-oreo-8-1   and  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203157/why-is-netguard-firewall-not-working-not-blocking-anything-on-my-note-9-oreo-8-1